# How can I connect to VPN server through C# program?

Tags: c#, vpn

I am a C# programmer, I have client needs:

He have 10 computers in office (VPN connection). one computer is server and all are clients. server computer has one folder it always updated time to time, I had to writer code to copy that folder from server computer. I made it and it works fine when I run that software in two system LAN connected.

VPN server needs user authentication. How can I connect to VPN server through C# program?

Comment: What does this have to do with nHibernate?

Comment: A quick google search revealed this [example](http://geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/articles/CSharpCodeToMaintainVPNConnectionProgramatically.aspx). Maybe it will get you started.